# Start Perl script via "Windows Command" through Cygwin

Tags: windows, perl, bash, cygwin

i have the following issue:

I try to start a perl script from the windows scheduler through cygwin

Steps i do:
Call process.bat file
In the process.bat i call bash with the parameter for the perl script

Symptoms:
If i call "perl scriptpath" directly from cygwin it works like a charm
If i call the script from the windows cmd with bash it will not work.

Command: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login  /cygdrive/c/scripts/testscript.pl
It prints the following:

```
Line 3: use: command not found
Line 4: use: command not found
Can't find file Test
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
print "Test";
```

Probably i'm making only a small mistake and cannot see it. It seems to interpret it with the windows cmd instead of the perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter passed to bash will be treated as a Bash script, not a Perl script. There is no reason to use Bash in this case - just invoke Perl directly:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\perl.exe /cygdrive/c/scripts/testscript.pl
```

---

If you *really* want to do it your way - calling a cmd script which calls a Bash script which calls a Perl script - then you would need to write a Bash script to invoke your Perl script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/cygdrive/c/scripts/testscript.pl
```

And pass that Bash script as the parameter when you invoke bash.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I will test it on Sunday and give you a Feedback :-)!

Comment: "*... you would need to write a Bash script ...*" that's not entirely true. Please see my answer for why.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to use option `-c` to have `bash` execute a command, like this:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -c /cygdrive/c/scripts/testscript.pl
```

From the `bash`'s man-page:

> **-c** string
>
> If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, unfortunately i cannot flag both as solutions, as both work for me, you got my upvote :-)